# input select2 value into input text with livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a problem when I want to display data from the database in the select2 option in the input text with livewire. in the image below I want to display some data to the input text according to the name selected in select2.[my page example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4qmv.png)

```
index.blade

<div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <h4 class="card-title ">1. Data Pasien</h4><hr>
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="">Find Pasien</label>
                                        <select class="js-example-basic-single w-100" id="selectpasien" wire:model="selected">
                                            <option selected disabled>Ketik Nama Pasien</option>
                                            @foreach($name as $item)
                                                <option value={{ $item->id }}>{{ $item->Nama_Lengkap }}</option>
                                            @endforeach
                                          </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                            <button type="button" id="btn-load-pasien" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-icon-text" wire:click="ShowData()" style="width: 100%">
                                                <i class="mdi mdi-account-check m-2"></i>Pilih Pasien</a>
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success mb-2" style="width: 100%" wire:click="halamanpas">
                                                <i class="mdi mdi-account m-2"></i>Create Data Pasien</a>
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger mb-2" style="width: 100%" wire:click="ResetAll">
                                                <i class="ti-reload btn-icon-prepend m-2"></i>Reset All</a>
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div><hr>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="">No. Rekam Medik</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" value="{{ $selected }}" wire:model="selected" readonly>
                                        <label for="">No. Ktp</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" id="#" readonly>
                                        <label for="">Nama Pasien</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" id="#" readonly>
                                        <label for="">Alamat</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" id="#" readonly>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

below is index.php

```
Index.php

{
    public $currentStep = 1, $totalStep = 2, $pasien_id, $nama = " ", $Nomor_Reg, $Nama_Lengkap, $selected = null, $sections = null, $halamanpas;
    protected $listeners = [];

    public function ShowData()
    {
        // 
    }

    public function hydrate()
    {
        $this->emit('select2');
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.admin.riwayat-penyakit.index', ['name' => DataPasien::all()])
        ->extends('layouts.admin')
        ->section('content');

    }
}enter image description here
```

is there any solution to solve this problem. thnx

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.